# Google Docs API - Spreadsheets which are Form Responses

Tags: forms, google-api, metadata, spreadsheet

So, I'm using the Google Docs API to extract spreadsheets programmatically.

However, I'm only interested in spreadsheets which are live feeds from form responses (survey responses). Is there a way of detecting this? So far the only approach I have is that the spreadsheet has a 'Form Responses 1' tab, which is quite a long way into the process; ideally I'd like to know before I download the file.

I'd be overjoyed by solutions which start with the form and tell you the relevant spreadsheet; ones which verify if a spreadsheet is a form's output are okay; knowing it's impossible would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get a list of the worksheets by using the Spreadsheets API.

Here is a link to the relevant documentation.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_information_about_worksheets

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know this is possible is by using Apps Script, which is Google Apps's scripting language based on Javascript.

You can use `Form.getDestinationId()` to find the target spreadsheet, like in this example :

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('1af5Ur_7IPHOXxdyqVXFF4tFA4WHx6PLf9uL56iPLMgI');
  Logger.log(form.getDestinationId())
}
```

More info about Apps Script's Form capabilities [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form?hl=FR).

Note that Apps Script has very limited integration capabilities, so if you're trying to build an integrated webapp it might get complicated (but not impossible).